# I want to send an email through ruby but I keep getting "cannot load such file -- sinatra" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

The below error keeps appearing. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/alambritis13/Desktop/project.rb/email.rb
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from C:/Users/alambritis13/Desktop/project.rb/email.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: If you read the first line of the error, it says it can't load the `sinatra` module. Did you install the `sinatra` gem?

Answer (score 0):

As lurker pointed out, it looks like you have an issue with your sinatra gem.

What gives `ruby -S gem which sinatra` ?

Try to install it using `gem install sinatra`.

You can also add this line at the beginning of your file `require 'rubygems'`